# Modify non-AD LDAP object with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ldap

I'm looking for a way to modify non-Active Directory LDAP objects using PowerShell.  I've found many scripts online to access LDAP object information but none that show how to modify them.  Below is the closest I've been able to get by combining various scripts I found online.  I can't get past the "$c.Bind()" line as I always get a "The LDAP server is unavailable" error.  I know the server name is correct and it is up and running.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.Protocols")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")

$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("cn=adminID,o=edu","password")
$NetWareServer=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier("LDAP://ldapserver.system.edu:636")
$c = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection($NetWareServer, $credentials)

$c.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = $true;
$c.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
$c.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Basic

$c.Bind() 

$r = (new-object "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyRequest")
$r.DistinguishedName = "uid=testID,ou=test,o=edu";

$a = New-Object "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeModification"
$a.Name = "description"
$a.Operation = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeOperation]::Add
$a.Add("testdescription")

$r.Modifications.Add($a)

$re = $c.SendRequest($r);

if ($re.ResultCode -ne System.directoryServices.Protocols.ResultCode]::Success)
{
    write-host "Failed!"
    write-host ("ResultCode: " + $re.ResultCode)
    write-host ("Message: " + $re.ErrorMessage)
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the certificate presented by `ldapserver.system.edu:636` is not trusted?

Comment: It could.  But I know very little about certificates and wouldn't know how to test that.

Comment: I had this problem and it was solved by taking the AD root cert and adding it to my trusted root authorities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using uid instead of cn for the credentials. Try connecting without SSL. Verify that the port and user information is correct and that the server and that port is reachable from where you are.

This is how I did it:

```
$c = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection -ArgumentList "ldapserver.system.edu:636"
$c.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = $true;
$c.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
$c.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Basic
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ConnectWithUser))
{
  $ConnectWithUser = Read-Host -Prompt "User:"
}
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ConnectWithPassword))
{
  $ConnectWithPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Password:" -AsSecureString
}
$ConnectWithUser = "uid="+$ConnectWithUser+",OU=admins,O=edu"

$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $ConnectWithUser,$ConnectWithPassword
$c.Bind($credentials)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change ("LDAP://ldapserver.system.edu:636") to ("ldapserver.system.edu:636") and it should work.

```
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("cn= Your account,ou=Your OU,o=Your Org,c=US","YourPassword")
$NetWareServer = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldapserver.system.edu:636")


$c = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection($NetWareServer, $credentials)

$c.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = $true;
$c.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
$c.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Basic

$c.Bind() 

$r = (new-object "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyRequest")
$r.DistinguishedName = "uid=aas,ou=yourou,o=yourorg,c=US";

$a = New-Object "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeModification"
$a.Name = "description"
$a.Operation = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeOperation]::Add
$a.Add("testdescription")

$r.Modifications.Add($a)

$re = $c.SendRequest($r);

if ($re.ResultCode -ne [System.directoryServices.Protocols.ResultCode]::Success)
{
    write-host "Failed!"
    write-host ("ResultCode: " + $re.ResultCode)
    write-host ("Message: " + $re.ErrorMessage)
}
```